# How to get specific value from array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
$Array = array("0","2","0","5","0");
```

and the specific value I want is 2 and 5, so the array will be like this:

```
$newArray = array("2","5");
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you have the values already why do you need to retrieve them from the array?

Comment: `[2, 5]` is not a "specific value." You've filtered elements from your array. This type of operation is called a "Filter", because it removes some elements of the array based on a given rule. In this case, the value must equal 2 or 5.

You may want to rephrase your question to something more like "How can I filter this array to retain only certain given values?"

Comment: I'll go even simpler: `$newArray = array($Array[1], $Array[3]);` Since we're being vague about the qualifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `"0"` is [falsey](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) you can just use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove all the "0" from your array:

```
$array = array("0","2","0","5","0","7","0");
$newArray = array_filter($array); // newArray is: ["2", "5", "7"]
```

Answer (score 0):

So you basically just want to remove zero's from your array?  I think this should work you just pass the function the array and the item you wish to replace (note this code is untested you may need to tweak it a little)

```
function array_replace($incomingarray, $tofind)
{
    $i = array_search($tofind, $incomingarray);
    if ($i === false) {
        return $incomingarray;
    } else {
        unset($incomingarray[$i]);
        return array_replace($incomingarray, $tofind);
    }
} 

$Array = array("0","2","0","5","0");
$a = array_replace($Array, 0); 
var_dump($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter`

```
function fil($var)
{
if($var == 2 || $var == 5)
return($var);
}
$array1 = array(0,2,0,5,0);
print_r(array_filter($array1, "fil"));
```

**Output**

```
 Array
(
[1] => 2
[3] => 5
)
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/281JEXxz)

Comment: Nice solution using it as a call back.  Could get complex if using a variable match params though surely as he'd have to generate the if clauses on the fly?